# How to display inva

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm new to coding. My question is how do I input the invalid argument into a  print back to them so "numin" should equal whatever invalid argument they put in. I've tried for an hour and I wouldn't know where to start. XD Like if they put in a String how can I have numin mirror it back to them on an else statement? Please and thanks

```
System.out.print("Enter Your favorite number:");
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int numin = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Your favorite number is: " + numin);
    } else {
        System.out.print(numin + " is not a valid argument please restart");

    }
```

Comment: Take user input in do while loop.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger i've tried that but keep getting errors. Would you have the code for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("Enter Your favorite number:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String numin = scanner.next();
        try {
            int intg = Integer.parseInt(numin);
            System.out.print("Your favorite number is: " + intg);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.print(numin + " is not a valid argument please restart");
        }
    }
```

Comment: took me so long XD and I failed. Thanks I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to declare numin. just check if it is int or not .

```
 System.out.print("Enter Your favorite number:");
    Scanner scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
    if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.print("Your favorite number is: " + scanner.nextInt());
    }else {
      System.out.print(scanner.next() + " is not a valid argument please restart");
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this answers OP's question?

Comment: numin is String here, any chance for String to be an instance of Integer?

Comment: @KhalidShah this works fantastic Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Akceptor finished the code

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.print("Enter Your favorite number:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String numin = scanner.next();
    try {
        int intg = Integer.parseInt(numin);
        System.out.print("Your favorite number is: " + intg);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.print(numin + " is not a valid argument please restart");
    }
}
```